# Recursive Method Call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a wrapper doing httpRequest, returning a Promise to an object and it works for the calls like this:

```
httpRequest.get("http://some.link/some?query=foo");
```

or

```
httpRequest.post("http://some.link", {"some":"requestBody"});
```

And, I need to implement concurrent calls retuning a Promise to an array like:

```
httpRequest
    .get("http://some.link/some?query=foo")
    .post("http://some.link", {"some":"requestBody"})
    .get("http://another.concurrent/request");
```

I know how to implement it using promise.all, but it gives bad experience to the user.

I need to find a way to call the function recurrently like we have in promise.

```
promise.then(res=>foo)
       .then(res=>bar)
       .then(res=>baz)
```

Comment: This isn't recursion.

Comment: "*but it gives bad experience to the user.*" - what are you talking about?

Comment: What do you mean by "*call the function recurrently like we have in promise.*"?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing isn't recursion.

You said you want concurrent HTTP requests that are represented by a single `Promise` (i.e. the `Promise` resolves after all 3 requests complete, in any order).

You can do that using `Promise.all` (using TypeScript syntax): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
let req1: Promise<Response> = httpRequest.get( "http://?query=foo" );
let req2: Promise<Response> = httpRequest.post( "http://?query=foo" );
let req3: Promise<Response> = httpRequest.get( "http://?query=foo" );

let reqAll: Promise<Response[]> = return Promise.all( req1, req2, req3 );

let responses: Response[] = await reqAll;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call all of them, collecting the resulting promises in an array. Then use [Promise.All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to handle the success or failure of them all.

See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on49jud7/) for an example of Promise.all:

```
Promise.all([
    asyncThing(),
    asyncThing(),
    asyncThing()
])
.then((promises) => {
    console.log("all resolved: ", promises)
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error("first rejection:", err);
})
```